# Is it possible to fetch a report from Tibco Spotfire to C# (console application)? I mean through API or any other mode?

Tags: c#, api, console, spotfire

I have a user account in Tibco Spotfire where i could see custom reports are created and stored. Is there any mechanism to fetch those reports to my console application if I pass the date parameters? Please help.

Comment: You can export to PDF and then use the filename (adding a date) to be able to fetch into another application : https://docs.tibco.com/pub/sfire-cloud/latest/doc/html/en-US/TIB_sfire_bauthor-consumer_usersguide/bauthcons/topics/en-US/preparing_a_report.html?force_isolation=true

Comment: I need to fetch the analysis automatically using C# code.

Comment: You will be able to fetch file automatically if it was saved.  The issue is with saving not fetching.